# List files sorted numerically

Tags: ls, filenames, sort, numbering

I have a bunch of files from `log1` to `log164`.

I'm trying to LIST the directory (sorted) in a UNIX terminal but the sort functions are only providing the format like this:

```
home:logs Home$ ls -1 | sort
log1.gz
log10.gz
log100.gz
log101.gz
log102.gz
log103.gz
log104.gz
log105.gz
log106.gz
...etc
```

What I want is

```
home:logs Home$ ls -1 | sort
log1.gz
log2.gz
log3.gz
log4.gz
log5.gz
log6.gz
log7.gz
...{more here}
log99.gz
log100.gz
log101.gz
log102.gz
...etc
```

Any suggestions in what I could use to do this?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

`bash`'s braces, `{}`, will enumerate them in order:

```
for file in log{1..164}.gz; do
    process "$file"
done
```

Answer (score 424):

Why not use the built-in GNU `ls` feature for this particular case:

> `-v` — natural sort of (version) numbers within text

For example:

```
ls -1v log*
```

Comment: On BSD/OSX this option is something else: `-v - Force unedited printing of non-graphic characters`.

Comment: Unfortunately the -v option is not available on AIX (6.1)

Comment: for MacOS this will work, couldn't find an option as mentioned, only `ls | sort -n`

Comment: Don't work on MacOS.

Comment: To make this work on MacOS. Install coreutils: `brew install coreutils` and add them to path `PATH="/usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin:$PATH"` (or just use `g`-prefix: `gls -lv`)

Answer (score 66):

With GNU ls (i.e. on Linux, Cygwin, or other systems that have GNU ls specifically installed):

```
ls -v
```

In zsh:

```
echo *(n)
```

In other shells:

```
echo log?.gz log??.gz log???.gz
```

Replace `echo` by `printf '%s\n'` if you want each file name on a separate line.

If you want file metadata as well (`ls -l`) and you don't have GNU ls, you'll need to call `ls` separately for each file name or group of file names that you want to see in lexicographic order.

```
ls -ld log?.gz; ls -ld log??.gz; ls -ld log???.gz
```

To avoid these difficulties, use enough leading zeroes in your file names so that the lexicographic sort is human-friendly (`log001.gz`, etc).

Comment: I'm getting bitten by this more often that I'd like to admit; is there a way, in ZSH, to default globbing to `(n)`?

Comment: @Michaël `setopt numeric_glob_sort`

Answer (score 40):

The GNU `sort` (as available on Linux,) has a "version sort" mode that interprets numberes inside non-numbers just the way you ask for:

From `man 1 sort`:

> ```
>     -V, --version-sort
>            natural sort of (version) numbers within text
> ```

(Creating empty test files to list:
`touch log1.gz log2.gz log3.gz log99.gz log100.gz log101.gz log102.gz`)

Your example case, adding the `-V` option (or `--version-sort`):

```
ls -1 log*.gz | sort -V
log1.gz
log2.gz
log3.gz
log99.gz
log100.gz
log101.gz
log102.gz
```

Answer (score 37):

While the solution `ls -1v` is  certainly the nicest in this particular case, I think it's good to have also one that works with `sort` as in the original question, since this works also when your input does not come from `ls`. In this case you can use:

```
ls -1 | sort -n -k1.4
```

The `-n` option tells sort to sort numerically, and `-k 1.4` sets the sort key to the first field (which is the whole filename in this case) starting from the 4th character up to the last.

Comment: In my case, `ls -1 | sort -n -k1.4` does not work. It gives unsorted ones at first up to 4 chars then sorted ones after 4th character. I used `ls -1 |sort | sort -n -k1.4` instead and it worked perfectly.

Comment: @Prabhu, instead, you could do `sort -k1.1,1.3 -k1.4n`. `sort` implementations are not required to be _stable_ so your approach won't work with all implementations.  See also the `-V` option of GNU and FreeBSD `sort`.

Answer (score 11):

if you use Mac or BSD try this:

```
ls -1 *.jpg | sort -n
```

Comment: -n didn't work for me on OSX, I needed -V

Comment: Worked beautifully!

Answer (score 3):

My version of Solaris doesn't support `ls -v` (grrr).  And the sort solution provided above 1) requires knowledge of the position of digits in the filename, and 2) doesn't handle things like multi-part version numbers.

The approach below is Solaris-compatible, doesn't require foreknowledge of the digit positions, and handles version numbers with 2, 3 or 4 components (like:  a-1.2, foo-5.6.7, bar_baz_9.10.11.12).  It also uses `sort -f` to fold upper- and lowercase together, and properly handles directories intermixed with files:

`ls -d | sort -f -t . -k 1,1 -k 2,2n -k 3,3n -k 4,4n`

Note that this version limits the first component to a single digit.

If your target operating system(s) supports `ls -v`, that is clearly the superior solution.

Answer (score 2):

Perl solution:

```
ls log*.gz | perl -ne 'sub getnum{ $_[0] =~ /log(\d+)\.gz/; $1 }; push @A, $_; END{ print sort { getnum $a <=> $b } @A}'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ ls
log101.gz  log102.gz  log103.gz  log104.gz  log105.gz  log106.gz  log10.gz  log1.gz
$ ls | sort -t . -n -k1.4
log1.gz
log10.gz
log101.gz
log102.gz
log103.gz
log104.gz
log105.gz
log106.gz
```

Comment: The `-t .` is superfluous here.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

I have files 1.jpg 2.jpg ... 18.jpg

`$ echo *.jpg | tr -s ' ' '\n' | sort -n`

`sort` is getting confused with `ls` output because of unprintable colour characters. If you try this:

`ls -1 --color=none *.jpg | sort -n`

it will work perfectly.

`sort` can ignore unprintable characters with `-i` option but it still doesn't work and I don't know why.

But you can always strip colour like this and `sort` will work:

`ls -1 --color=always *.jpg | sed -r "s/\x1B\[([0-9]{1,2}(;[0-9]{1,2})?)?[mGK]//g" | sort -n`

I hope one day `sort` will have an option for this.

Answer (score -1):

Command:

```
ls -l | sort --human-numeric-sort
```

Comment: Please use proper syntax & explain what your command should yield