# Glob with Numerical Order

Tags: bash, filenames, wildcards

I have this list of pdf files in a directory:

```
c0.pdf   c12.pdf  c15.pdf  c18.pdf  c20.pdf  c4.pdf  c7.pdf
c10.pdf  c13.pdf  c16.pdf  c19.pdf  c2.pdf   c5.pdf  c8.pdf
c11.pdf  c14.pdf  c17.pdf  c1.pdf   c3.pdf   c6.pdf  c9.pdf
```

I want to concatenate these using ghostscript in numerical order (similar to this):

```
gs -q -sPAPERSIZE=a4 -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=out.pdf *.pdf
```

But the shell expansion order does not reproduce the natural order of the numbers but the alphabetical order:

```
$ for f in *.pdf; do echo $f; done
c0.pdf
c10.pdf
c11.pdf
c12.pdf
c13.pdf
c14.pdf
c15.pdf
c16.pdf
c17.pdf
c18.pdf
c19.pdf
c1.pdf
c20.pdf
c2.pdf
c3.pdf
c4.pdf
c5.pdf
c6.pdf
c7.pdf
c8.pdf
c9.pdf
```

How can I achieve the desired order in the expansion (if possible without manually adding `0`-padding to the numbers in the file names)?

I've found suggestions to use `ls | sort -V`, but I couldn't get it to work for my specific use case.

Comment: You *could* just use two digit numbers in all cases, so the alphabetical order will match the numerical order.  Unless you want to do things the hard way.

Comment: 3 digit numbers, at least! Remember Y2K.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Depending on your environment you can use `ls -v` with GNU coreutils, e.g.:

```
gs -q -sPAPERSIZE=a4 -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite \
   -sOutputFile=out.pdf $(ls -v)
```

Or if you are on recent versions of FreeBSD or OpenBSD:

```
gs -q -sPAPERSIZE=a4 -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite \
   -sOutputFile=out.pdf $(ls | sort -V)
```

Comment: `ls -v` will `natural sort of (version) numbers within text` so that can be used as well...

Comment: @Sundeep: Indeed, but this seems to be a GNU coreutils only solution.

Comment: yeah, seems like GNU specific - http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/

Comment: @Sundeep: The `-V` feature of `sort` is not specified by POSIX either. However, it seems to have spread farther, for example both FreeBSD and OpenBSD `sort` support it.

Comment: oh ok, can you add these details to answer as well? I came across this answer while searching for similar problem (glob in numerical order) and seeing `ls` used I checked out if it had option by itself instead of piping to sort :)

Comment: NEVER parse ls! Use `stat -c "%n" *` instead.

Comment: @Peter: In general I agree, but there are exceptions

Comment: and also I would change my comment above since `stat` with `%n` is not really best either due to whitespace being allowed in filenames...use `printf '%s\0'`, and things like `xargs -0` or `while read`... I wrote an answer that has that.

Answer (score 41):

Once more, [zsh's glob qualifiers](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers) come to the rescue.

```
echo *.pdf(n)
```

Answer (score 18):

If all the files in question have the same prefix
(i.e., the text before the number; `c` in this case), you can use

```
gs  …args…  c?.pdf c??.pdf
```

`c?.pdf` expands to `c0.pdf` `c1.pdf` … `c9.pdf`. 
`c??.pdf` expands to `c10.pdf` `c11.pdf` … `c20.pdf`
(and up to `c99.pdf`, as applicable). 
While each command-line word containing pathname expansion character(s)
is expanded to a list of filenames sorted (collated) in accordance
with the `LC_COLLATE` variable,
the lists resulting from the expansion of adjacent wildcards (globs)
are not merged; they are simply concatenated. 
(I seem to recall that the shell man page once stated this explicitly,
but I can’t find it now.)

Of course if the files can go up to `c999.pdf`,
you should use `c?.pdf c??.pdf c???.pdf`. 
Admittedly, this can get tedious if you have a lot of digits. 
You can abbreviate it a little; for example, for (up to) five digits,
you can use `c?{,?{,?{,?{,?}}}}.pdf`. 
If your list of filenames is sparse
(e.g., there’s a `c0.pdf` and a `c12345.pdf`,
but not necessarily every number in between),
you should probably set the `nullglob` option. 
Otherwise, if (for example) you have no files with two-digit numbers,
you would get a literal `c??.pdf` argument passed to your program.

If you have multiple prefixes
(e.g., `a<number>.pdf`,
`b<number>.pdf` ,
and `c<number>.pdf` ,
with numbers of one or two digits),
you can use the obvious, brute force approach:

```
a?.pdf a??.pdf b?.pdf b??.pdf c?.pdf c??.pdf
```

or collapse it to `{a,b,c}?{,?}.pdf`.

Comment: This is the best answer because it's beyond any claims of sketchy use of `ls`, `stat`, or anything else; and also works in bash as requested.

Answer (score 5):

*If there are no gaps*, the following could prove helpful (albeit sketchy and not robust concerning edge-cases and generality) -- just to get an idea:

```
FILES="c0.pdf"
for i in $(seq 1 20); do FILES="${FILES} c${i}.pdf"; done
gs [...args...] $FILES
```

If there *may be* gaps, some `[ -f c${i}.pdf ]` check could be added.

**Edit** also see [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/33910/11539), according to which you could (using Bash) use

```
gs [..args..] c{1..20}.pdf
```

Comment: It is generally a good idea to quote your shell variable references (e.g., `"$FILES"` and `"$i"`) unless you have a good reason not to, and you’re sure you know what you’re doing.  (By contrast, while braces can be important, they’re not as important as quotes,  so, for example, `"c$i.pdf"` is good enough.)  A command like `gs  [ ` *`…args… `* `]  $FILES`, where `$FILES` contains a space-separated list of files, may seem like a good reason to use `$FILES` without quoting it (because `"$FILES"` won’t work in that context).  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  But see [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/80216), in particular, [my answer to it](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/80216#286350), for notes on how to handle multi-word variables as arrays in bash (e.g., `FILES=("c0.pdf")` and `FILES+=("c$i.pdf")`); also [this answer](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/310361/80216#310364), which uses the technique I suggest.

Answer (score 2):

Just quoting and fixing Thor's answer... NEVER parse ls!

You can use `sort -V` (a non-POSIX extension to sort):

```
printf '%s\0' ./* | sort -zV \
    | xargs -0 gs -q -sPAPERSIZE=a4 -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH \
        -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=out.pdf
```

(for some commands, apparently for gs is such a command, you need "./*" instead of "*"... if one doesn't work, try the other)

Comment: The  _don't parse ls output_ is because ls displays the file names newline-separated while newline is as valid as any in a file name, but here you're doing the same thing with `stat` but adding several other issues (like problems with filenames starting with `-`, problem if there are too many files, `stat` being a non-portable command). And because you used the split+glob operator without adjusting IFS or disabling globs, you'll still have issues with filenames with space or tab or wildcard characters.

Comment: To use GNU `sort -V` reliably, you'd need `${(z)"$(printf '%s\0' * | sort -zV)"}` in `zsh` (though `zsh` has `(n)` for numerical sort already) or `readarray -td '' files < <(printf '%s\0' * | sort -zV)` in `bash4.4+`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas thanks, and you are right that newline can be a concern, but that isn't the only reason not to parse ls. And yeah I was lazy and didn't add -- either. But I should have used printf...I'll change that.

Comment: for `ls` alone (that is without -l), what are those _other concerns_? Note that `--` wouldn't help for a file called `-`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas there are other differences between versions... like some print "total 0" on there, and the newest ls versions even stick quotes around things where you don't want them... `touch \"test\"; ls -1` for example shows `'"test"'` on my ls. It's simply not meant to be parsed... it's a user interface, not a scripting command.

Comment: the `total x` is only for `ls -l/n...`. The quoting is only for output to a terminal (not a pipe like here). For a POSIX compliant `ls`, the only problem would be the newlines. But `-v` is not a POSIX option anyway. Now, I've just realised that `busybox ls` now also supports `ls -v` and busybox `ls` is one of those implementations that are not POSIX compliant as it does some mangling even when stdout is not a terminal.

Comment: `*` -> `./*` to avoid problems with  some file names with `gs`.

Comment: Note also the OP's comment "I've found suggestions to use ls | sort -V, but I couldn't get it to work for my specific use case."