# How can I sort filename in correct numerical order

Tags: files

How can I fix problems with Filename order?

For example,

```
ls
```

yields files as follows:

```
basename1
basename11
basename12
basename13
[omitted]
basename2
basename20
basename21
....
basename3
```

PROBLEM

11-19 are parsed prior to 2 and 3.

Comment: [List files sorted numerically](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33909/list-files-sorted-numerically)

Comment: Related:  [Glob with Numerical Order](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/38317/80216).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List files sorted numerically](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33909/list-files-sorted-numerically)

Comment: Try `man ls`. There is an option for this.

Answer (score 5):

You can use sort

```
ls basename* | sort -V
```

The -V option of sort is short for "version" but it actually orders by "name and number" which is exactly what you seem to be looking for. See sort man page:

> -V
>   --version-sort
>
> ```
>  Sort by version name and number.  It behaves like a standard sort,
>  except that each sequence of decimal digits is treated numerically
>  as an index/version number
> ```

#### GNU `ls`:

`ls -v` can version sort the listing.

Comment: `sort -V` is also a GNU extension.

Answer (score 2):

With the `zsh` shell, you can make globs sort numerically with the `numericglobsort` option or the `n` glob qualifier:

```
print -rC1 basename*(n)
```

Note that if you pass the glob expansion to the `ls` command specifically, `ls` will perform its own lexical sorting, so you'll lose the sorting done by `zsh`.

With the GNU implementation of `ls`, you can use its `-U` option however to disable sorting:

```
ls -ldU basename*(n)
```