# problem with quoting ls output

Tags: bash, find

I want to join some png files into a pdf. The command

```
convert *png out.pdf
```

works, but gets the ordering wrong. It turns out that

```
ls -v *png
```

gives the ordering that I want, therefore I want to pass its output on to convert.

I have tried

```
convert `ls -v *png` out.pdf
```

but this doesn't work since the filenames contain spaces and parentheses.

Telling `ls` to set the filenames between double quotes via

```
convert `ls -vQ *png` out.pdf
```

doesn't work either since the quotes seem to get removed in the substitution.

What can I do?

Comment: [Don't parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)...

Comment: If you have a GNU based system, perhaps something like `find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*.png' -print0 | sort -zV | xargs -0` will give the desired ordering?

Comment: Or rename them (even links to them in a separate directory) with sequencing numbers as prefixes?

Comment: Thanks steeldriver, that seems to go in the right direction but how can I tell xargs to call the command once with all arguments instead of once for each?

Comment: To be precise, I use `find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*png' -print0 | sort -zV | xargs -0 -I files -t convert files out.pdf` but that calls convert once for each filename.

Comment: ilkkachu posted an answer that worked, but when i wanted to accept it it had disappeared. this is the thing that worked for me: `eval convert $(ls -Qv *png) out.pdf`. I know that I could also rename the files, but the format with spaces and parentheses is how they are exported by an ipad app, and I just want to transform them into something useful with minimal effort. So ilkkachu if you post your answer again, or whoever deleted it undeletes it, I will accept it.

Comment: @user313032, you can't, not with GNU xargs, it insists on one file per command when using `-I`.  BSD find has `-J` which is similar, but doesn't have that limitation.

Comment: @user313032, Yeah... using `eval` can work here, but it's... a bit like pointing around with a gun. I deleted that answer to work on a less dangerous solution.

Comment: This doesn't make sense.  **Glob expansion sorting should be the same as `ls` sorting.**  Unless you have directories involved, but your `png` extension seems to indicate that you don't.  I question your conclusions and request that you *show* us the "wrong order" you are getting.

Comment: The -v option changes the sorting.

Comment: @user313032, aha, I was checking a BSD man page for the `-v` option of `ls`; silly me.  There are [other ways](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/33909/135943) to get the files sorted the way you want, though.  I would not use `eval` for this use case no matter what.

Comment: Yes I can see now why eval is very bad style. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your file names don't have any newlines in them, you might be able to do it with just telling the shell to split the output of `ls` only on newlines, not any whitespace as the default. The [splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Word-Splitting) is controlled by the `IFS` variable, any characters contained in `IFS` are used as delimiters.

```
IFS=$'\n'      # set it to just a newline
convert $(ls -vd ./*.png) output.pdf
```

This may still have problems if the file names are funny enough, or if `ls` mangles them for display. When printing to a terminal, `ls` usually lists the files in multiple columns. But when the output doesn't go to a terminal (the shell reads it, here), it acts as if `-1` was given.

---

To work with the idea you started with, you *could* use `eval`.

> eval: eval [arg ...]
>   Combine ARGs into a single string, use the result as input to the shell, and execute the resulting commands.

But the problem with `eval` is that anything and everything in the command line gets parsed again, and even stuff that's usually safe, isn't. Think of a file called `$(touch HELLO)` and what happens if a name like that is dropped on the command line.

Also, if you go this way, you may want to use `--quoting-style=shell` instead of `-Q` as it may match the shell's processing of the special characters more closely. (Both may be specific to GNU ls, but I think `-v` is, too.)

Comment: Both solutions work, but I don't understand what the thing with IFS does. Does it mean that the output of the `ls` will be broken apart along newlines? This wouldn't work since we call `ls` without the `-1` option, no?

Comment: @user313032, edited, clarified. Basically the `-1` is implied whenever the output of `ls` goes anywhere but a terminal. (It's as if they tried to make it work with scripts even though some characters in file names are still a problem.) You can try something like `ls | cat` to see the difference.

Comment: Thanks I see. How can I see the value of `IFS`? The command `echo $IFS` only gives a newline.

Comment: @user313032, and always will, because without quotes, its contents are split to words... along the characters of `IFS` itself. Since it's going to have special characters in it, it may be best to use something like `echo "$IFS" | od -c` to get them [escaped in the C-style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C).

Comment: You'd also need to disable globbing for your split+glob operator: `IFS=$'\n'; set -f; mv $(set +f; ls -vd ./*.png) out.pdf`

Answer (score 2):

If you have a recent GNU-based system (whose `sort` provides a similar `-V` natural-version sort) you could sort using that, and read the result into an array:

```
while read -rd '' f; do 
  files+=("$f")
done < <(find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*png' -print0 | sort -zV)
```

Then you should be able to expand the array within your `convert` command:

```
convert "${files[@]}" out.pdf
```

Comment: Note that bash 4.4 supports `readarray -td ''`

Comment: Thanks @StéphaneChazelas - I was searching for exactly that last night, but I only have bash 4..3 currently. I was also hoping you'd show up with a nice `zsh` solution ;)

Answer (score 1):

With `zsh`, the `(n)` glob qualifier gives you a similar sorting order as GNU `ls -v`:

```
convert ./*.png(n) out.pdf
```

On a GNU system, with `bash`,  `zsh`, `yash`, `mksh` or `ksh93`:

```
eval "files=($(ls --quoting-style=shell-always -vd ./*.png))"
convert "${files[@]}" out.pdf
```

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU Parallel it looks like this:

```
ls -vd ./*png | parallel -Xj1 convert {} out.pdf
```