# FreeBSD natural sort with ls and recurssion

Tags: freebsd, ls, sort

In `Ubuntu` I can do a recursive search with a natural sort quite easily. A simple `ls -1Rv` will list file names only in a natural sort with all sub directories. An example output would be:

```
.:
test4
tmp2
tmp3

./tmp2:
test1
test2

./tmp3:
test3
```

It lists the current contents and then it traverses each directory. Everything is separated nicely.

With `FreeBSD` the `-v` option doesn't exist. When I didn't have sub directories I could do a `ls -1 | sort -n` for a natural sort. However, now that I have sub directories the pipe into `sort -n` doesn't work nicely. The `ls -1R | sort -n` predictably sorts into one giant list. An example output would be:

```
./tmp2:
./tmp3:
test1
test2
test3
test4
tmp2
tmp3
```

Instead of each sub directory separated in its own list, we have one giant list. Is there anyway to duplicate the `ls` functionality from `Ubuntu` in `FreeBSD` where I can get `FreeBSD` to list out and sort each list separately?

My searching has found topics like [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33909/list-files-sorted-numerically), but they all use the pipe method and don't seem to talk on what happens with sub directories. I've also read the [FreeBSD ls manual](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ls&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD%2012.2-RELEASE%20and%20Ports&arch=default&format=html), but it does not mention having a natural sort. I didn't see anything helpful in the [FreeBSD sort manual](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sort&sektion=1&apropos=0&manpath=FreeBSD%2012.2-RELEASE%20and%20Ports) either.

Comment: Do you mean `sort -n` or `sort -V` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider it cheating but you could install either:

- [LSD (LSDeluxe)](https://www.freshports.org/sysutils/lsd/) which is a very capable upgrade/variant.
- [GNU Coreutils](https://www.freshports.org/sysutils/coreutils/) which are the tools you are used to. Or just [GNU ls](https://www.freshports.org/misc/gnuls/) alone.

Install:

```
pkg install lsd
pkg install coreutils
```