# Remove files except latest one by numeric order

Tags: bash, shell-script

I am trying to remove files within a bash script.

I can list the latest file with:

```
ls | grep core | tail -n 1
```

and rename it like `keep-core-2994-xyz.bin`, then remove the rest with:

```
rm -f core-*
```

and then rename the latest to the original. In this way, I can keep the latest file and remove the rest. This works fine for this scenario:

```
-rw-------  1 root root  47M Sep  3  2017 core-2994-xyz.bin
-rw-------  1 root root  47M Sep  3  2017 core-3012-xyz.bin
-rw-------  1 root root  79M Sep  3  2017 core-3106-xyz.bin
```

However, this one: `core-10000-xyz.bin` causes trouble:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  55M Sep  3  2017 core-10000-xyz.bin
-rw-------  1 root root  47M Sep  3  2017 core-3012-xyz.bin
-rw-------  1 root root  79M Sep  3  2017 core-3106-xyz.bin
```

... because this time, I need to keep the one I want with `head`, not with `tail`.

Is there any effective way to remove files except the latest one which were created by this order? (Here, `core-3012-xyz.bin`)

The file timestamps are unreliable; this is an embedded device and timestamps can change due to the internet connection, so I can't list them by timestamp.

This is an embedded device and I don't want to compile it with zsh; I'd like a bash-only solution, please.

Answer (score 4):

With `zsh`:

```
rm -f -- *core*(n[1,-2])
```

Where the `n` glob qualifier turns on `numericglobsort` for that one glob expansion and `[1,-2]` selects the first to second last.

Or:

```
rm -f core-<1-4294967295>-xyz.bin(n.[1,-2])
```

If you want to make it more specific, where `<1-2147483647>` matches on sequences of digits that represent numbers in the range of valid pid numbers and the `.` qualifier restricts the expansion to *regular* files only.

Note that `core-bar-123` would sort *before* `core-bar-1000` but also before `core-foo-1`. The numeric sort is used when it comes to comparing numbers when the part leading up to them is the same. Here `core-bar` sorts before `core-foo`. Adding numbers to either won't change that.

To only consider the numbers when sorting, you could do something like:

```
extract_numbers() {
  set -o localoptions -o extendedglob
  REPLY=${${${REPLY//[^0-9]##/-}#-}%-}
}
```

```
rm -f --  *<->*(.no+extract_numbers[1,-2])
```

Where `extract_numbers` converts `some123file5123with3numbers` to `123-5123-3` which is then used for `n`umeric ordering.

Comment: I like this a lot, but to be fair, the question has a [tag:bash] tag!

Comment: @MarcusMüller, sure. In `bash`, just do `zsh -c 'that code'` but why would anyone still use `bash` in this day and age :-b. In anycase, the answer would be useful to users landing here with similar requirements and not being limited to using bash

Comment: Somehow, I do agree ;)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas because as i wrote in question this is an embedded device and there is no reason to compile it together with zsh and believe me this is our last concern.

Answer (score 0):

Oh i found the solution.

```
ls -v | grep core | tail -n 1
```

will do the trick.

Reference:

[List files sorted numerically](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33909/list-files-sorted-numerically)

Comment: I'm sorry I've downvoted this, but: ***Never*** parse `ls` output. For example, this all breaks when a file has a newline in its name – which is a perfectly legal character. So, not really a solution.

Comment: also note that as Stéphane has pointed out, you could at least restrict your `ls` to only look into files that are called `core-*` to begin with.

Comment: But: you've linked to a good resource, but you focused on the answer producing output meant for *human* consumption, not for *computer* consumption. [This](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/33988/106650) answer uses the same "listing" method that Stéphane uses in their answer here. However, the "hard" part is selecting only the right file, and that's what's missing.

Comment: Your attempt @obayhan is incomplete, it's not going to delete anything.

Comment: `$ ls -v -1 core-* | tail -n 1 | xargs rm -f`

Comment: @MarcusMüller these are dump output files controlled by us, they don't have a chance get an empty or non-alphanumeric string in their names.So there is no reason not to parse "ls output" (: + this was an example, in real system dumps can get prefixes like xyz-core-1234, thats the reason of the grep. + i can guarantee there is anything else in there containing "*core*"  Anyway thanks for the reminders to produce a "common" answer but my problem is not common.

However they are unrelated to my question.

As i said it is an embedded linux and i have all control over that directory.

Comment: @MarcusMüller so please dont  think it is an uncontrolled Desktop

Comment: @tansy please read the question carefully